# MySQL auto generate values

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

I search a complex SQL code, I have one right now to generate a value random between 0 - 100000 when it does not exists.

Now I want the next level, I need to insert a new value when the value its random string, its start from 1 and I need to changes this (chart count) to like 32 when the string now will return a string on 32 chars.

The string much contain all chars type include spical charts.

The problem is I use this algoritme for discount-vouchers and a numbers have not soe many combinds like numbers include a-z chars have.

I hope somebody can help me on my searching.

Answer (score 1):

A function to generate a random string from a collection of characters of your choosing:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION random_str() RETURNS char(32)
BEGIN
  DECLARE chars varchar(500);
  DECLARE rs char(32);
  SET rs = '';
  SET chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*_';
  WHILE (LENGTH(rs) < 32) DO
    SET rs = CONCAT(rs, SUBSTRING(chars, RAND() * LENGTH(chars), 1));
  END WHILE;
  RETURN rs;
END
```

A unique index on your value field:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX IX_str (str);
```

Then, I would just be sure to catch the once-in-a-lifetime exception in my client code, or you could do something like this to insert new values:

```
DECLARE c int;
DECLARE rs char(32);
SET c = 1;
WHILE (c > 0) DO
  SET rs = random_string();
  SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE str = rs;
END WHILE;
INSERT INTO my_table (str) VALUES (rs);
```

Comment: And if the random str need to be unik from orther values in my MySQL?

Comment: It sounded like you had that part figured out already. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you still keep the random number, but insert through password or sha1 this would essentially take your RAND   and encrypt the RAND to create a random string.  you just dont need to decrypt it because the encrypted value of rand, is your random string.

the other way is to create a GUId on your code side of things

Comment: If your MySQL has the base64 functions, then perhaps creating a binary string from a random number and base64-encoding it might do what you need.

Comment: Yes, but i dont want that way :) i want to generate it on thats way, i allredy use GUID and more of taht stuff, :)